# load csv file into BQ - too many positional args

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I tried loading a sample data file [csv] in BQ. Since CSV has header I wanted to skip first row, Following is the code

```
  project_id1> load prodtest.prod_det_test gs://bucketname/Prod_det.csv prodno:integer,prodname:string,instock:integer --skip_leading_rows=1
```

Issue: Too many positional args, still have['--skip_leading_rows=1']. Please suggest how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
bq load --skip_leading_rows=1 prodtest.prod_det_test gs://bucketname/Prod_det.csv prodno:integer,prodname:string,instock:integer
```

The -- arguments come at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks positional args issue resolved but I am getting 
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: Probably, you have a row that has an empty column instead of a Integer and you didn't specify that column may be null. Build a more descriptive schema in a file and use it instead of the command line.

Comment: thanks for your response. I could load csv into BQ through browser tool mode but when I try via cmd line, I am getting this error. In other post, it is referred to use gcloud components update, still I get the same issue. I will check on the column nullable option